# No sobreescribir el xml

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy pasando un objecto a xml y luego el xml lo paso a objeto a un datagridview, el tema aqui es que me sobreesribe los datos, como podria hacer que no se sobre escriban, solo se aculumen.
codigo object to xml:

```
class_Proveedor Prov = new class_Proveedor();
            cliente.nombreC = textBox1.Text;
            cliente.direccion = textBox4.Text;
            cliente.Genero.genero = comboBox1.Text;
            cliente.tipob.tipob = textBox2.Text;
            clientlist.Add(cliente);
            SerializeToXml<List<Client>>(clientlist, @"C:\Users\Curso\Desktop\xmls\Clientes.xml");

            void SerializeToXml<T>(T obj, string fileName)
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                    System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);

                    ser.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Se a guardado exitosamente");
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR!!!");

                }
            }
        }
```

Tambien dejo el codigo de xml a objecto donde lo meto a l grid

```
  XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(@"C:\Users\Curso\Desktop\xmls\Clientes.xml");
            List<Client> clientlist = new List<Client>();
            clientlist = DeserializeFromXml<List<Client>>(xml.OuterXml);
            foreach (var item in clientlist)
            {
                DataGridViewRow rows = new DataGridViewRow();
                rows.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.nombreC });
                rows.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.direccion });
                rows.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.Genero.genero });
                rows.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.tipob.tipob });


                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows);
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar FileMode.Create por FileMode.Append?

Comment: Gracias, tu comentario fue de mucha ayuda.